# Зависание установщика Debian

Tags: debian

Здравствуйте. Не могло бы уважаемое сообщество помочь мне с решением страной проблемы при установке Debian на систему.
Суть проблемы: при начале установки ОС на систему появляется экран выбора метода установки ОС, после выбора вида установки система зависает. Данная проблема возникает абсолютно на всех установочных дисках и флешках, были перепробованы Debian 9.3, 9.1, 7.7, Ubuntu 14.04, 16.04, Mint 16. Системы семейства Windows устанавливаются без проблем (испробованы xp, 2003, 7). 
Установка проводилась на заведомо робочий ПК с характеристиками: Core-i5 2500, Gigabyte GA-Q67M-D2H-B3, Kingston 4gb 1333 (memtest OK).
Я знаю что некоторые версии ядра Linux имеют похожую проблему когда в BIOS включены опции C1E, C6, поэтому они были заблаговремено отключены.

Comment: проще всего взять другую материнскую плату/графический адаптер, у которой не будет описанной проблемы.

Comment: Проще но неприемлемо. Никто не даст деньги на замену мат. платы.